# Return an entire word according to a subset of it with Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Suppose I have this string

`str = "The rain in Spain"`

And I want to return the first word that contains the two letters "ai" (i.e. "rain")

What must the regular expression be?

Comment: have you looked up tutorials? have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Regex can be used to find the first word in any given string

```
    \w*ai\w*/m
```

/m param is for multi line & will return the first match
replace ai within the parenthesis to the required char matching for any string. i.e ab | we | slkd etc
Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: `()` capturing group is unneeded... And why the space before `/m`?

Comment: right, Update the regex, capturing group was a greedy step, that is also causing the more steps to find out the match.